# R - How to improve this recursion for running mean?

Tags: r, recursion

I wrote a function that calculates a simple running mean, per the weighted average recurrence formula, as follows:

```
cumulative_mean <- function(prev_step=c(1, 0), new_data=c())
{
  # easy sample data argument: new_data=sample(0:100,100,replace=T)

  if (length(new_data) == 0)
  {
    return("done!")
  }
  else
  {
    #prev_step[1] = current time tick step
    #prev_step[2] = previous mean

    new_mean <- ((prev_step[1] - 1) / prev_step[1] * prev_step[2]) + ((1/prev_step[1]) * new_data[1])
    new_tick <- prev_step[1] + 1

    result <- c(prev_step[1], new_data[1], new_mean)
    print(result)

    return(cumulative_mean(c(new_tick, new_mean), new_data[-1]))
  }
}
```

This seems to work well enough, except for choking, with a stack overflow error for data that is around 4000 in length.

I'm trying to think of a way I can pass less data to the next recursion loop, but not coming up with anything. My system memory never spikes, so I conclude the overflow is from R specifically.

How can this be restructured so as to make less of a hit on R's nesting/function call capabilities?

Comment: `dplyr::cummean` or `cumsum(x) / seq_along(x)`

Comment: I get an error that mentions `options(expressions=)`, which on my system is set to 5000. You can up that limit if you want and your function will work on longer vectors, but I don't really see what else you can do other than not using recursion for this.

Comment: Please provide an example of what you are trying to do with an expected output.

Comment: Marius - roger that, and thanks!

Comment: alistaire - thanks, but the point is for me to learn R, not just call libraries - tho in real life clearly that would be the way to go :)